# How could I pass an array of objects through to my Express / SQL Server (react)

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, reactjs, express

I have an array of objects that I would like to pass through to my back end (SQL Server).

Below is the array of objects this is the exact results from

```
console.info(results)
```

Here is array of objects (this is named results)

```
[0] [
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'bmbm,nn',
[0]     question: 'Is the keyboard separate from the screen?',
[0]     state: 'problem specified'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Does the keyboard tilt?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is it possible to find a comfortable typing position?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Do you have a good keyboard technique?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Are the characters on the keyboard clear and readable?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: "Is your mouse or other pointing device suitable to the task you're using it for?",
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'bnmgjvgh',
[0]     question: 'Is the mouse (or other pointing device) located sufficiently close to you?  ',
[0]     state: 'Declined with solution defined'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Does the mouse (or other pointing device) work smoothly at a speed that suits you?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is there support for your wrist and forearm when using the mouse(or other pointing device)',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Can you easily adjust the software settings for speed and accuracy of the pointer?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Are the characters on your screen clear and readable?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the text size on your screen confortable to read?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the image on your screen free from flicker and jitter?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: "Is your screen's specification suitable for its intended use?",
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the brightness and/or contrast on your screen adjustable?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

This is how I was originally going to pass it though to my sql however I am stuck with the logic of how to do so.

```
app.post("/post-question-answers", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("!called");
  try {
    let results = req.body.results;

//This is the console.info posted earlier 

    console.info(results);

    await sql.connect(config, function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // create Request object
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.input("Results", sql.VarChar, results);
      // query to the database and get the records
      request.execute("dbo.StoreAnswers", function(err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // send records as a response
        res.json(recordset);
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.info(e);
  }
  res.statusCode = 400;
  res.statusMessage = "bad request";
  // res.json({ message: "Email Missing" });
});
```

All I need to know is how is this doable. Do I need to iterate through and rip out each separate variable? Do I need to use user defined tables within SQL Server? Can I pass a object straight into the database?

I have no clue what lead to follow and have been wasting a lot of time on this problem.

Please any advice is appreciated

Comment: As I think your question is not clear and requires editing.

Comment: WHat isnt clear I am happy to update if needed :)

Answer (score -1):

You can bulk insert by using raw query

Comment: This form of your answer should be in the comment.

Comment: Okay thanks Is there anywhere I can view examples of these ?